# Translation of “wir bilden zusammen Gewalten”

Tags: meaning-in-context, lyrics

These two lines are from the song *Walther* by the German rapper Absztrakkt:

> Doch ich rufe die Jungen und ich versammel die Alten
>   Um wieder zusammen zu halten, wir bilden zusammen Gewalten

I understand the first part, but I have problems with the second sentence. What does *bilden zusammen Gewalten* mean? I know that *Gewalt* is violence/authority, but I don’t know how violence can be the object of *bilden.*

Comment: *Gewalten* doesn't necessarily mean violence/authority - See *Gewaltenteilung*

Comment: You are probably aware that texts published by rap poets often have a very liberal approach to language, and that sometimes words are chosen just in order to achieve a rhime without too much respect of established meaning and usage of the words?

Answer (score 3):

Group 1 and group 2 *»bilden zusammen Gewalten«* means:

> Group 1 and group 2 will constitute/represent a huge power *(Macht)* if they join together.

The groups in this case are the young and the old.

*»Bilden«* is used here as

> [2. a. durch Sichgruppieren, Sichorganisieren formen, herstellen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/bilden)

and *»Gewalten«* not as violence but as power:

> [1. Macht, Befugnis, das Recht und die Mittel, über jemanden, etwas zu bestimmen, zu herrschen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gewalt)

Comment: Thank you. What about "Um wieder zusammen zu halten"?

Comment: @LearningMath: _»um wieder zusammenzuhalten«_ translates to _»to stick together again«_ → Duden meaning 2 of [_»zusammenhalten«_](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zusammenhalten): fest zueinanderstehen; eine (gegen äußere Gefahren o. Ä.) fest gefügte Einheit bilden

Comment: In this context, i would translate _Gewalt_ loosely as _force_, as in to _forceing social and political change_